# Combobox EF group by

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using c# - entity framework. This code not working when I using group by. Without group by is working well.

```
myComboBox.DataSource = myEntites.stocks_head
                                 .Select(m => m)
                                 .Where(m => m.stocksHeadContainerNumber != "")
                                 .GroupBy(m => m.stocksHeadContainerNumber )
                                 .ToList();

myComboBox.DisplayMember = "ContainerNumber";
myComboBox.ValueMember = "ContainerNumber";
```

`}` //drop exception here

What's the correct form?

Comment: could you please post the definition of stocks_head? What's the ContainerNumber?

Comment: What data does your query returns without your `GroupBy` clause ?

Comment: Incidentally the `Select(m => m)` is redundant. Also, when asking a question, you need to clarify "doesn't work". Doesn't _compile_ or throws a runtime exception? If so, what exception, etc, etc.

Comment: This is, the exception: A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll after myComboBox.ValueMember = "ContainerNumber"; line the next line is: }

Comment: If you use GroupBy you do not have a ContainerNumber. You have a key and a grouping. Fire up Linqpad and run this query to see what I mean.

Comment: Could you write me what is the correct form?

Comment: Why do you group? What are yo trying to achieve? I think you only have to sort.

Comment: No, it's necessary. I've a list for a same container numbers. Need to show only one in the other list.

Answer (score 0):

Now you told what you want to achieve it appears to be simply getting the first item of each grouping:

```
myComboBox.DataSource = myEntites.stocks_head
                                 .Select(m => m)
                                 .Where(m => m.stocksHeadContainerNumber != "")
                                 .GroupBy(m => m.stocksHeadContainerNumber )
                                 .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault())
                                 .ToList();
```

This is the same a [MoreLinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/)'s `DistintBy`.

(Giving this information directly probably would have given you an answer in minutes.)